# XCODE iOS 8 iAD Load Error

Tags: ios8, iad

I have a universal app that has been in use for several years with iAD Banner working. This was first implemented in iOS4, so it does not use ".canDisplayBanner" and does use the delegate.  This has worked in all iOS versions.

With XCODE 6, it still works on simulator and device, iPhone and iPad, in development, when running on iOS7 target (aka, developer ad loads most of the time).  If I run the same build on an iOS8 target, everything is the same, but ad Load ALWAYS gets error (3) ads not available, and NEVER become available.

As I understand it, iAd Banner should always return ads in development - regardless of iTunesConnect or provisioning.  I have changed iOS Settings->Developer->(iAd Stuff), but no effect.  Unfortunately, the Apple AdViewBanner and iAD docs appear to have only had formatting changes for iOS8, and are still essentially iOS6 docs.   Searching the net, I can not find any one else with an iOS8 issue with iAd.

I can not determine is this is a coding issue/change for iOS8, or some type of Apple iAD service issue.  Suggestions?

Comment: I forgot to say this fails to generate (load) TEST ADS in development mode when target is iOS8 device.

Comment: After about 24+ hours, the ads finally started.  I guess the iAD cloud server must need time to update to support device with new iOS...